# Are random forests ideal for feature selection with two completely independent datasets?

Tags: r, random-forest, feature-selection

I have two independent dataframes:

**Observation of animal frequencies in a site:**
Each row represents a site, where the animal frequencies (response variables?) sum up to 100 and the other variables (predictors?) are factors.

| Animal 1 | Animal 2 | Animal_n | Altitude | Region | Geography_Type | Chronology | Site_Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 40 | 20 | 10 | North | Coast | Roman | Urban |
| 25 | 25 | 50 | 100 | South | Mountain | Late Roman | Farm |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

**Presence absence observations of plants in a site**: each row represent a site.

| Plant 1 | Plant 2 | Plant_n | Altitude | Region | Geography_Type | Chronology | Site_Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 10 | North | Coast | Roman | Urban |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 100 | South | Mountain | Late Roman | Farm |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

Unfortunately, I cannot combine these dataframes in any way as the observations come from different sites/chronologies and the observations with a matching site ID and chronology are too few (less than 40). In other words, I have no unique ID and I can't concatenate/combine/merge the dataframes in any way.

My goal is to select the features that are most important for the decision of having certain plants or certain animals at certain altitudes, regions, site type, etc.

My initial thought was to use a random forest, but it would not work as I cannot combine the dataframes. What should I look into to solve this type of problem? Ideally, I need something supervised because I need to know what are the most important factors.

I am sorry about the question, I am trying using random forests for the first time.

Comment: If these two data frames are completely independent, measuring different things, then why are you trying to combine them? Why not do two models for each frame and answer a different question for each? What is your research question, what is your goal?

Comment: I am sorry, I should have been more specific. Both dataframes are independent because they consist of different observations, although the sites where the observation are located share categorical variables. However, we are talking about food consumption/production = farming practices and this is why it can be meaningful (to me) to have a model which includes both information. For instance, the presence of a Cereal X can be important because it can be produced as animal fodder

Comment: For exporatory purposes you can try like this: 1) train model on animals (RF or other algorithm if you prefer to preserve error structure like something like multivariate multiple regression + some simulation package); 2) simulate on plants for rows where no data for animals available; 3) train on plants; 3) simulate missing values in animals; 4) concatenated two data sets by rows; 5) use RF for classification/regression.

Comment: Hi @Artem, which technique do you recommend for simulations based on a RF (if this is what you are suggesting)? A multi-variate based bootstrapping? My main end goal is to understand which categorical variable (predictor) is more important in the different distribution of animals/plants in the sites.

Comment: I think that for exploratory purposes regour is not important. So you can omit my comment about error structure. So train RF model on animals and predict  missing locations on plants, then vice-versa on plants, then concatenate datesets with filled-in values from previous steps, then carry out feature selection on the resultant dataset. If you share representative sample of your data (`dput`) then I'll try to illustrate.